# Scroll Trigger: How to play the whole animation not by every page scroll once it enters the trigger element?

Tags: jquery, gsap, scrollmagic, scrolltrigger

I have this animation that plays on every page scrolling. What I want to achieve is to play the whole animation when it triggers the `id section` of the pinned element. So when it enters the pinned element, it should play the whole animation, not by every page scroll.

A good reference is in here to better understand what will be the output

> https://squareup.com/us/en/why-square under `Look and feel like a pro.`

Is this possible using scrolltrigger and gsap? I'm very new to this jquery plugin and still discovering the features and controls of this.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 108;

const currentFrame = index => (
  `https://dev.jin.services/fazz/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/assets/images/imagesequence/home-banner-${(index + 1).toString().padStart(3, '0')}.jpg`
);

const images = []
const banner = {
  frame: 0
};

for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = currentFrame(i);
  images.push(img);
}
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.to(banner, {
  frame: frameCount - 1,
  snap: "frame",
  ease: "none",
  scrollTrigger: {
    scrub: true,
    pin: "#pin-banner",
    trigger: "#hero-lightpass",
    duration: '100%',
  },
  onUpdate: render // use animation onUpdate instead of scrollTrigger's onUpdate
});

images[0].onload = render;

function render() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(images[banner.frame], 0, 0); 
}
```

```css
html {
height: 100vh;
}

body {
height: 5000px;
background: #000;
}
#pin-banner {max-width:1220px;margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:100%;}
#hero-lightpass {width:100%;}
.pin-spacer {padding:0 !important;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div style="height:600px;"></div>
    <div id="pin">
        <div id="pin-banner">
            <canvas id="hero-lightpass" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:600px;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 42px;color:#fff;">TEST</h1></div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.0/ScrollTrigger.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you're using very old versions of GSAP and ScrollTrigger so I'd recommend you to update them.

Regarding what you're trying to do, basically remove the `scrub: true` key:value pair in your config and that should do it. Also in the newest versions duration is deprecated in favor of setting a specific end value, which can use a relative value:

https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger

Scroll down to Usage & special properties to find it.

Finally if you're still having issues, please head to the GSAP forums.